# Center-aligning text on console in Python

Tags: python, shell, text, console

I am creating a simple console-based Python (version 2.4) script that will be run on a Bash shell. It is a simple menu-based script that displays a set of options to the user and will do specific tasks depending on the user input.

When the script starts, I want it to clear the screen and display the menu in the center of the screen. I can get the console width from `stty size`. How do I go about center-aligning the text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`str.center`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.center)

```
s = "hello world"
s.center(40)
>>> '              hello world               '
```

Comment: `string.center` is deprecated and "removed in Python 3". What is the alternative?

Comment: @Qwertie The _function_ in the `string` module (e.g. `string.center('foo', 10)`) has been removed in Python 3. The _method_ on `str` objects is fine (e.g. `'foo'.center(10)`).

Answer (score 8):

If you are using python version `3.6` (as I love to use it instead of `2.7`) you can use the `caret` character in the `format` function:

```
>>> '{:^50}'.format('sample text')
'                   sample text                    '     # with a length of 50.
```

If you want to fill the gap you use:

```
>>> '{:*^50}'.format('sample text')
'*******************sample text********************'     # * is the fill character.
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import shutil

def print_centre(s):
    print(s.center(shutil.get_terminal_size().columns))
```