# Basic Python Alignment Trouble

Tags: python

I'm trying to align the a phrase and cannot get past syntax errors. This is my code:

```
print(f'{Rodneys Pricing Table:^10}')
```

Is there something I'm missing here? I want the phrase "Rodneys Pricing Table" to print center-aligned.

I've tried everything I've learned so far in my introductory programming class, I had alignment exercises I did and now I cannot get it to work here.

Comment: Not sure how you plan on centering a 21-char string within a 10 char space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string needs to be quoted to work as a string constant, and the field width needs to be longer than 10 since the string itself is longer than that.  Also make sure to use a *different* quote style than the f-string.

For example:

```py
>>> print('1234567890'*4); print(f'{"Rodneys Pricing Table":^40}')
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
         Rodneys Pricing Table
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand that the number being specified is the amount of space I'm giving the string.

Answer (score 0):

f-strings are used to render expressions. Expression can have spaces, but then you wouldn't need an f-string for that.

Instead, you could make a variable.

```
phrase = 'Rodneys Pricing Table'
print(f'{phrase:^10}')
```

However, "centering" text in the terminal is:

1. Terminal dependent, not something `print()` knows about

   - The `^10` creates a string of at least ten "spaces", then puts your text within that, so...
2. Not going to occur when `^10` is shorter than your string.

Refer [Center-aligning text on console in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907236/center-aligning-text-on-console-in-python)

Comment: f-strings are used to render  ̶v̶a̶r̶i̶a̶b̶l̶e̶s̶  expressions (ie. `print(f'{"Rodneys Pricing Table":^10}')` would work if the available space was more than 10)

Comment: You can put any expression inside `{}`. So you can put a quoted string literal.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that `^10` creates a string *at least* 10 characters wide, which will be padded on the left and right as needed if `phrase` is not itself at least 10 characters.